# Using Python Pandas' dataframe, how to tweak the display and apply a calculation on sequential log rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking for some assistance in cracking the 2 following tasks using Python and Pandas.

Here's the input sequential log table:

```
user_id token   action_id   action_timestamp
7       223     1           timestamp1
12      191     1           timestamp2
45      667     2           timestamp3
7       223     3           timestamp4
12      191     2           timestamp5
12      339     1           timestamp6
7       223     2           timestamp7
12      339     2           timestamp8
7       564     1           timestamp9
12      778     1           timestamp10
91      551     1           timestamp11
12      778     4           timestamp12
12      778     5           timestamp13
91      551     5           timestamp14
91      551     3           timestamp15
91      551     2           timestamp16
45      122     1           timestamp17
```

The first desired outcome should select only those rows that have action_id 1 and action_id 2 for a token, and display their timestamps as columns- per user, per token:

```
user_id token   timestamp_action_id_1   timestamp_action_id_2
7       223     timestamp1              timestamp7
12      191     timestamp2              timestamp5
12      339     timestamp6              timestamp8
91      551     timestamp11             timestamp16
```

The second desired outcome is a calculation of the average time measured from action_id 1 to action_id 2 across all tokens, per user:

```
user_id action_id_1_to_action_id_2_time_delta_average
7       <avg of time delta for token 223>
12      <avg of time delta for tokens 191 and 339>
91      <avg of time delta for token 551>
```

Thanks in advance!

---

Update:
Here's the code that implements mozway's answer:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [7, 12, 45, 7, 12, 12, 7, 12, 7, 12, 91, 12, 12, 91, 91, 91, 45],
    'token': [223, 191, 667, 223, 191, 339, 223, 339, 564, 778, 551, 778, 778, 551, 551, 551, 122],
    'action_id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1],
    'action_timestamp': [f'timestamp{x}' for x in range(1,18)]
})

# For all columns
df.pivot(index=['user_id', 'token'], columns='action_id', values='action_timestamp').add_prefix('timestamp_action_id_').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

# Only for the desired columns 
df2 = df[df['action_id'].isin([1,2])].pivot(index=['user_id', 'token'], columns='action_id', values='action_timestamp').add_prefix('timestamp_action_id_').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df3 = df2[~df2.isnull().any(axis=1)].reset_index(drop=True)
df3

user_id     token   timestamp_action_id_1   timestamp_action_id_2
0   7   223     timestamp1  timestamp7
1   12  191     timestamp2  timestamp5
2   12  339     timestamp6  timestamp8
3   91  551     timestamp11     timestamp16
```

However, if the log table has a repeating action for the user within a token, an 'Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape' error occurs.
Here's the table with a repeating action:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'user_id': [7, 12, 45, 7, 12, 12, 7, 12, 7, 12, 91, 12, 12, 91, 91, 91, 91, 45],
    'token': [223, 191, 667, 223, 191, 339, 223, 339, 564, 778, 551, 778, 778, 551, 551, 551, 551, 122],
    'action_id': [1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 2, 1],
    'action_timestamp': [f'timestamp{x}' for x in range(1,19)]
})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add minimal reproducible example, or at least an attempt. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For the first step `pivot` your dataframe:

```
df.pivot(index=['user_id', 'token'], columns='action_id', values='action_timestamp').add_prefix('timestamp_action_id_')
```

Second filter, pivot, calculate the delta, groupby user_id and take the mean:

```
(df[df['action_id'].isin([1,2])]
   .pivot(index=['user_id', 'token'],
          columns='action_id',
          values='action_timestamp')
   .add_prefix('timestamp_action_id_')
   .assign(delta=lambda d:d['timestamp_action_id_2']-d['timestamp_action_id_1'])
   .groupby('user_id')['delta'].apply(lambda x: x.dt.total_seconds().mean())
   .dropna()
)
```

output (using random timestamps):

```
user_id
7     813000.0
12    -29000.0
91   -601000.0
```

*N.B. unfortunately I cannot test/run the code at the moment, so consider it pseudocode*

Comment: Thank you for the answer and direction.
First step works only if the action_id is not repeating, however, if it does then the code breaks on 'Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'.
I'll add code to the orig question.

Comment: @Aerodyne I could now check, I slightly updated the code and it works with the provided example. Can you provide an example with duplicate? You might have to replace `pivot` with `pivot_table`. If there are several timestamps how do you want to aggregate them? take the first?

Comment: Goal is to run some time delta calculations between different actions. Since number of actions per token is small, I thought to spread them wide as columns. user_id and token are the index columns, and then rest of the columns are the timestamps of all the actions in the token. It's challenging because different users may have a different number of actions per token.
Perhaps the column idea is not that great for this goal? Perhaps a group by user and token then loop through the timestamps in that token group may be better?